# What emacs tools are available for Perl programmer? How to install them?

Tags: perl, emacs, elisp

I found many of .el files from emacswiki.org that are useful for perl programming in emacs. Help me set it up. I am finding it troublesome to install all elisp files on my ubuntu 12.04.

1. Perl completion
2. Perl-pod-gt
3. Perl now
4. C Perl mode
5. Perl-quote

[emacswiki.org/emacs/PerlLanguage#Perl](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/PerlLanguage#Perl)

Comment: `cperl-mode` ships with Emacs. What files are you having issues with, and what is your exact problem? Usually you just download each file to a local file and do whatever it says in the Commentary section inside the file. Typically, make sure the directory is in your `load-path` and add a small snippet to your `.emacs` file.

Comment: The language is named "Perl", not "PERL".

Comment: Since tripleee's question you seem to have added a list of items you want to use, but you still have not explained what you're having difficulty with, so I can only reiterate: "what is your exact problem?"

Comment: I do not see a specific question here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a ton out there, but I primarily just use CPerl mode.

Its fairly basic, but serves me well.

M-x cperl-mode

Comment: CPerl mode is fine but I want oprions like auto-complete/suggestions, color-coding, indentation, (If possible even features equivalent to Intelli-sense offered by Visual Studio for C++)

I read about these in emacs wiki.org:
1. Perl completion
2. Perl-pod-gt
3. Perl now
4. C Perl mode
5. Perl-quote

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PerlLanguage#Perl

Comment: CPerl mode has much of that. Emacs comes with autocompletion, it doesn't parse the language, but at the very least it will autocomplete the names of identifiers for you. CPerl mode should be color coded, and it should indent intelligently. Autocomplete would be M-/, if you don't see color add (font-lock-mode 1) to the top of your .emacs file and restart emacs. Indentation you can do by highlighting a region C-[space], then M-x indent-region (which might be mapped to tab already for you, I don't remember if I customized this).

Answer (score 4):

[Sepia](http://p3rl.org/Sepia) is probably the most ambitious. I haven't used it extensively, but best I can tell it aims to be the [SLIME](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/) of Perl programming.

Answer (score 3):

PDE, you can get it from cpan, module name is Emacs::PDE